# Excel VBA Error 1004 cant set visibility

Tags: vba, excel

I have a weird error with excel vba. I am trying to set the visibility to false inside a pivot table for date values. My code works fine on a dummy table, but it return an error (1004) on my real table.

```
Sub MultiItemPivotFilter2()
Dim PI As PivotItem


Sheets("Pivot_stocks_1").PivotTables("Pivot_Stocks_1").RefreshTable


 For Each PI In Sheets("Pivot_stocks_1").PivotTables("Pivot_Stocks_1").PivotFields("date2").PivotItems


 If DateValue(PI.Name) < DateValue(Sheets("Pivot_stocks_1").Range("J13").Value) Then

             PI.Visible = False
          Else
              PI.Visible = True
          End If

    Next PI
End Sub
```

The error occurs in line `PI.Visible = False`

(Unable to set Visible property of the PivotItem class)

Comment: Try adding `pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone` before `RefreshTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help you:

[unable to set the visible property of the pivotitem class](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8ac328d9-9daf-4e5b-9daf-7507d0c0abc7/unable-to-set-the-visible-property-of-the-pivotitem-class-excel-2007?forum=exceldev)

> Excel sometimes does not remove old entries from pivotcache on which pivot table is based.In that some item may be there which is not in source data but excel keeps it in cache for optimizing.Refreshing cache does not solve issue.Only way is remove the cache and recreate it.

Comment: It did not resolve the error. Could be there another reason?

Answer (score 0):

You should always do your select true loop and then do a select false loop. The reason being that Excel does them one at a time and will not allow you to have everything hidden in a pivot table, it will error out (or what have you) so:

```
Sub MultiItemPivotFilter2()
    Dim PI As PivotItem

    With Sheets("Pivot_stocks_1").PivotTables("Pivot_Stocks_1")
        .RefreshTable

        'Loop first setting all to "True"
        For Each PI In .PivotFields("date2").PivotItems
            PI.Visible = True
        Next PI

        'Loop then setting any "False"
        For Each PI In .PivotFields("date2").PivotItems
            If DateValue(PI.Name) < DateValue(Sheets("Pivot_stocks_1").Range("J13").Value) Then
               PI.Visible = False
            End If
         Next PI
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope that makes sense!

**Edit**

Even if it doesn't fix your problem you should always implement this logic when hiding pivotItems